# Build mode is always debug

Tags: .net, build, debugging, release

I have a ASP.NET application that I am trying to build in release mode, but upon inspection ([Assembly Information](http://assemblyinformation.codeplex.com/)) it is always showing up in debug mode.  I've also changed the Web.config entry to specify that the compilation mode should not be debug, but still no luck.  Does anyone have any ideas how to get my build into release mode?

**Edit**:  The project is VB.NET.

Comment: What language is the project in?

Comment: Are you looking at the right DLL?  Not sure how ASP.NET does it, but the Release build version goes to another directory (bin\Release instead of bin\Debug).

Comment: I tried creating just a simple class library solution and built it in release mode.  The assembly went into the release directory, yet when I inspect the assembly with the application I have posted above, and my own, the build mode is showing debug, even though it's in the release directory.  Any ideas?  Thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Assembly Information application I had posted above isn't quite working the way I'd expect.  I added code to my AssemblyInfo.vb file and I can see that my assembly is being built in release mode, yet the application is saying it was a debug build.  Perhaps the application works better on an older or newer version of .NET, but it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 2):

In the `Build` menu, select `Configuration Manager`.  There you can change your `Active solution configuration` to `Release` instead of `Debug`.

An alternative, is to get `Properties` of the project, select the `Build` tab, and select `Release` for the project's `Configuration`.

Comment: I have selected release in the build menu.  There is a drop down to build in either debug or release, and I have release selected.

Comment: In Configuration Manager, when you have selected Release, are all the projects in the list below set to Release?

Comment: Good catch, though I have a single project solution that I have set to build in release mode and when I inspect it with the utility (I haven't checked the source code of the utility, but I do have my own application that checks to see if JITTracking is enabled) the build mode is still showing debug.  I have cleaned the solution and rebuilt, no dice.  Is there something I'm still missing?

Comment: IsJITOptimizerDisabled I believe is the check for Release, but I think IsJITTrackingEnabled should be false too.  For your project build properties, is the "Optimize code" checkbox checked?

Comment: If you are referring to "Properties/Compile/Advanced Compile Options", I have "Enabled optimizations" checked.  Thank you for your help so far.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We ran across the same issue.  The project was set to build in release, as well as the containing solution.  It even spit out the dll to the release folder - but upon inspection it was a debug build.  I found the solution in the project's advanced compiler settings.  It appears when the Generate debug info is set to anything other than none - the project always builds in debug mode.

Change this setting to none to fix the issue.